# Hamming's algorithm returns the coded sequence to the initial sequence

Tags: hamming-code

I need help with this problem, so if anyone is willing to help me, I would be grateful.

How can I return the Hamming sequence that has been encoded to the initial sequence?

For example, I have the sequence `111101000010`, how to return it to the starting sequence, it is Hamming code `(12,8)`? I'm not asking for someone to do this problem completely for me, but to explain how to do this, since I didn't find any principle of Hamming's way of decoding on the Internet?

I've tried this:
I separated the control bits from the information bits. I got that the control bits are: `C1 = 1, C2 = 1, C3 = 1` and `C4 = 0`. The information bits are `10100010`.

Now I drew the binary table and checked the control bits, and got the values `​​C1 = 0, C2 = 1, C3 = 1` and `C4 = 1`. From here I see that the control bits `C1` and `C4` do not match the above control bits, so I conclude that there is an error. From here I don't understand what to do next, I found on the internet that the positions `C1` and `C4` are added together, so you get `5`, and as in the fifth bit there is an error and that bit needs to be inverted, when I invert that bit the initial sequence is `10101010`, and when encoding this with Hamming code I get `111101001010`. From the attached it can be seen that the sequence obtained differs from the sequence at the beginning by only one bit at position `9`. I don't know how to solve this, nor if my procedure is correct, please help .

Thanks in advance!

Best regards!